# Como pegar partes de um texto em php

Tags: php, regex

Como pegar do texto a parte

> "name":"Placa-Mãe ASUS p/ Intel LGA 1151 ATX ROG STRIX Z270E GAMING,DDR4,Aura Sync, áudio Gamer, Rede Intel, SLI/CFX, Wi-Fi, USB 3.1 Frontal,HDMI/DP"

e

> "price":1095.9

lembrando que de dependendo do link informado o name e price será diferente porem, sempre tera name .* e price .*

```
$texto = "
string(43488) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Etag: "a6152a2c"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 188487
X-TIME: 1493043126.194
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: max-age=219, public
Expires: Mon, 24 Apr 2017 14:17:06 GMT
Date: Mon, 24 Apr 2017 14:13:27 GMT
Set-Cookie: incap_ses_297_582873=HDYgfiL0VibiGqTihigfBAcI/lgAAAAAOgjiY0SVKeRwJpG/EqcKgg==; path=/; Domain=.kabum.com.br
Set-Cookie: ___utmvmPwutOXo=yrlhYeFzkwB; path=/; Max-Age=900
Set-Cookie: ___utmvaPwutOXo=XmSBlTw; path=/; Max-Age=900
Set-Cookie: ___utmvbPwutOXo=pZE
    XNfOValo: vtJ; path=/; Max-Age=900
X-Iinfo: 5-61671947-0 0CNN RT(1493043207095 0) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1)
X-CDN: Incapsula

      window.lpTag=window.lpTag||{};if(typeof window.lpTag._tagCount==='undefined'){window.lpTag={site:'85687252'||'',section:lpTag.section||'',autoStart:lpTag.autoStart===false?false:true,ovr:lpTag.ovr||{},_v:'1.6.0',_tagCount:1,protocol:'https:',events:{bind:function(app,ev,fn){lpTag.defer(function(){lpTag.events.bind(app,ev,fn);},0);},trigger:function(app,ev,json){lpTag.defer(function(){lpTag.events.trigger(app,ev,json);},1);}},defer:function(fn,fnType){if(fnType==0){this._defB=this._defB||[];this._defB.push(fn);}else if(fnType==1){this._defT=this._defT||[];this._defT.push(fn);}else{this._defL=this._defL||[];this._defL.push(fn);}},load:function(src,chr,id){var t=this;setTimeout(function(){t._load(src,chr,id);},0);},_load:function(src,chr,id){var url=src;if(!src){url=this.protocol+'//'+((this.ovr&&this.ovr.domain)?this.ovr.domain:'lptag.liveperson.net')+'/tag/tag.js?site='+this.site;}var s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('charset',chr?chr:'UTF-8');if(id){s.setAttribute('id
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#carousel').flexslider({
              animation: 'slide',
              animationSpeed: 300,
              slideshowSpeed: 4000,
              controlNav: false,
              animationLoop: false,
              slideshow: false,
              itemWidth: 64,
              itemMargin: 5,
              asNavFor: '#slider',
              start:function(slider){
                  $('#slider .flex-direction-nav').remove();
                  $("#imagem-slide li").gkzoom();
              }
          });

          $('#slider').flexslider({
              animation: 'fade',
              animationSpeed: 300,
              controlNav: false,
              animationLoop: false,
              slideshow: false,
              sync: "#carousel",
              start: function(slider){
                 if ($('ul.slides li').size() < 11) {
                       $('ul.flex-direction-nav').remove();
                 }
              }
          });
      });
      $(document).ready(function(){

        var add_dias_uteis = function(date, dias) {
                var copiedDate = new Date(date.getTime());
                var dias_corridos = 0;
                for(i = 0; i < dias; i) {
                    copiedDate.setDate(copiedDate.getDate()+1);
                    if (!(copiedDate.getDay() == 0 || copiedDate.getDay() == 6)) {
                        i++;
                    }
                    dias_corridos++
                }
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + dias_corridos);

                return date;
            };

        $('.cep').mask('99999-999');
        var PATH = 'http://'+window.location.host;

          $("#calcula_frete").on('submit', function(ev){
              if($("#calc_cep").val().length == 9){
                  ev.preventDefault();
                  var id = "#janela1";
                  $('#table-calcular').html("");
                  $("#agendamento_texto").html("");
                  $('#table-cal');
                  var alturaTela = $(document).height();
                  var larguraTela = $(window).width();

                            if(value.valor == 0) {

          dataLayer = [{"productsShelf":[],"productsDetail":[{"position":"1","name":"Placa-M�e ASUS p/ Intel LGA 1151 ATX ROG STRIX Z270E GAMING,DDR4,Aura Sync, �udio Gamer, Rede Intel, SLI/CFX, Wi-Fi, USB 3.1 Frontal,HDMI/DP","category":"Hardware/Placas-m�e/P/ Processador Intel/ASUS","brand":"Asus;","price":1095.9,"id":"84264","available":true}],"visitor":"","pageType":"product","breadcrumb":[{"url":"http://www.kabum.com.br/hardware","name":"Hardware"},{"url":"http://www.kabum.com.br/hardware/placas-mae","name":"Placas-m�e"},{"url":"http://www.kabum.com.br/hardware/placas-mae/p-processador-intel","name":"P/ Processador Intel"},{"url":"http://www.kabum.com.br/hardware/placas-mae/p-processador-intel/asus","name":"ASUS"}]}];

    ";
```

Comment: Rapaz, o texto é isso tudo ai de cima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codigo final

```
<?php

function getKabum($urlCompleta) {

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true) and libxml_clear_errors();
    $header = "X-Forwarded-For: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$urlCompleta");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.kabum.com.br");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DomXpath($DOM);


    $titulo = $xpath->query('//h1[@class="titulo_det"]')->item(0);
    $preco = $xpath->query('//span[@class="preco_desconto"]')->item(0);
    if (empty($titulo->nodeValue)) {
        preg_match('/(\\"productsDetail\\"\:\[{\"position\":\"1\",\"name\":\"[^\"]+\")/', $DOM->textContent, $t);
        preg_match('/(\\"productsDetail\\"\:\[{\"position\":\"1\",\"name\":\".*?\"),(\"price\":\d*[\.|\,]*\d*)/', $DOM->textContent, $output_array);        
        $title =  substr($t[1], 42, -1);
        $price =  substr($output_array[2],8);

        $titulo->nodeValue = $title;
        $preco->nodeValue = $price;
//    print'<pre>';
//    var_dump($DOM);
//    print'</pre>';
    }
    $retorno = array("titulo" => $titulo->nodeValue, "preco" => $preco->nodeValue);
    return $retorno;
}

$produto [] = getKabum("http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/produtos/descricao.cgi?codigo=84264");
$produto [] = getKabum("http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/produtos/descricao.cgi?codigo=84404");
//aqui o curl montou diferente
$produto [] = getKabum("http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/produtos/descricao.cgi?codigo=75332");
$produto [] = getKabum("http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/produtos/descricao.cgi?codigo=63735");
$produto [] = getKabum("http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/produtos/descricao.cgi?codigo=85198");
$produto [] = getKabum("http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/produtos/descricao.cgi?codigo=41620");
$produto [] = getKabum("http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/produtos/descricao.cgi?codigo=34217");
$produto [] = getKabum("http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/produtos/descricao.cgi?codigo=77987");
$produto [] = getKabum("http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/produtos/descricao.cgi?codigo=63327");

foreach ($produto as $value) {
    if ($value['titulo'] == '') {
        print_r($value);
    }
    print $value['titulo'];
    print "<h1>" . $value['preco'] . "</h1><hr>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você deve se lembrar que em uma regex sempre haverá um delimitador, quando você cita que os arquivos terão name.* e price.* não é o suficiente para resolver seus problemas, isso só define aonde a regex deve começar a buscar.

> Você deve sempre informar o resultado desejado e também mencionar as
>   inconsistências que podem ser encontradas.

Falar somente "lembrando que dependendo do link informado o name e price será diferente porem, sempre terá name .* e price .*" não é o suficiente, porém fiz uma resposta mais genérica para seu problema, tente:

```
("name":".*?")("price":\d*[\.|\,]*\d*)
```

Em suma o primeiro *Capture Group*: `("name":".*?")` captura qualquer numero de  carácteres incluindo especiais que tenham `"name":"` antes deles e terminem com `"`

O segundo `("price":\d*[\.|\,]*\d*)` captura um numero qualquer de dígitos (1-9) após `"price":` que possam ter como separador `.` ou `,` para casa decimal

Answer (score 2):

Vendo seu texto para analise juntamente com a tag PHP, imagino que você esta fazendo um CURL.

#### Sugestão PARSER

O ideal nesses casos, por se tratar de um analise de HTML, é usar um parser.
Caso o faça sugiro [Simple Html Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

#### Sugestão Analisador JSON

Analisando o contexto do HTML justamente com o que deseja, é possível verificar que se trata de extração de um dado presente em um JSON.

```
dataLayer = [{"productsShelf":[],"productsDetail":[{"position":"1","name":"Placa-M�e ASUS p/ Intel LGA 1151 ATX ROG STRIX Z270E GAMING,DDR4,Aura Sync, �udio Gamer, Rede Intel, SLI/CFX, Wi-Fi, USB 3.1 Frontal,HDMI/DP","category":"Hardware/Placas-m�e/P/ Processador Intel/ASUS","brand":"Asus;","price":1095.9,"id":"84264","available":true}],"visitor":"","pageType":"product","breadcrumb":[{"url":"http://www.kabum.com.br/hardware","name":"Hardware"},{"url":"http://www.kabum.com.br/hardware/placas-mae","name":"Placas-m�e"},{"url":"http://www.kabum.com.br/hardware/placas-mae/p-processador-intel","name":"P/ Processador Intel"},{"url":"http://www.kabum.com.br/hardware/placas-mae/p-processador-intel/asus","name":"ASUS"}]}];
```

Sugiro trabalhar com analise do mesmo. Para isso basta capturá-lo e usar `json_decode($json, true)` assim o conteúdo se torna um `array`, e fica mais fácil de se trabalhar com ele.

#### Solução por REGEX

Caso ainda assim quira fazer por REGEX pode usar :

`("name":"[^"]+")|("price":(?:\d{1,3}.?)+[.,]\d{1,2})`

Veja funcionando em [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/N9zhw2/1).

O fato de retornar outras tags `name` é que a pesquisa não é muito especifica sendo apenas `"name":` a parte exata.

Comment: consegui, obrigado. Porém, tem algumas paginas, não sei qual o motivo, mas o textContent está vindo muito diferente. Tem como pegar o codigo fonte da pagina com o curl? toda vez que eu dou um print o $html ex: $html = curl_exec($ch);  ele monta a pagina no meu navegador. vou postar uma resposta para voce como ficou meu codigo.

Comment: Tipo isso view-source:http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/produtos/descricao.cgi?codigo=75332 assim sempre será igual

Comment: @Herick de fato ele vai montar o HTML na sua pagina, pois o conteúdo que você tem em sua variável `$html` é um html, e seu navegado esta tentando interpretá-lo. Caso queira exibir o html use `echo htmlspecialchars($html)`

Comment: você sabe qual o motivo desse sistema funcionar em minha maquina localhost e não funcionar quando jogo para o servidor final uolhost.(obs: no servidor final o site kabum funciona e o submarino da esse erro.) Dando a seguinte msg: Access Denied You don't have permission to access "http://..."